# New Tensorflow 2.4 GPU issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, ubuntu-20.04

### Question

Tensorflow 2.4.1 doesn't recognize my GPU, even though I followed [the official instructions from Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) as well as the ones from [NVIDIA for CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) and [NVIDIA for cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) to install it in my computer. I also installed it in conda (which I'm not sure if it is needed?).

When I try the [official way to check if TF](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#setup) is using GPUs, I get 0:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

Num GPUs Available: 0
```

### Specifications

#### Hardware:

My NVIDIA fulfills the requirements [specified by Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements).

#### Software

I installed CUDA (with CUPTI) and cuDNN as mentioned above, so I got:

- `ubuntu 20.04 LTS`
- `NVIDIA driver = 460.39`
- `CUDA (+CUPTI) = 11.2`
- `cuDNN = 8.1.1`

In a conda environment I have:

- `python = 3.8`
- `tensorflow = 2.4.1` (which I understand is the new way of having the GPU support)

and I installed extra the `cudatoolkit==11.0` and `cudnn==8.0` for `conda` as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/lsc-psd/tensorflow-2-1-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-gpu-even-though-cuda-10-1-with-solution-7b44297843a).

### Procedure followed:

It did not work when I didn't have the `conda` extra packages, and it still doesn't work even though I installed those extra packages.

Comment: So when you followed the official tensorflow installation instructions, I guess you skipped over the bit that says "TensorFlow supports CUDA® 11". You need to install CUDA 11.0

Comment: You are right that it mentions `TensorFlow supports CUDA® 11` but I thought they meant 11.x, not specifically 11.0. I will downgrade CUDA to 11.0 as well as the cuDNN to 8.0.4 and try again. However, if I understood correctly, I can safely delete the extra `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn` installed via `conda` because they are not really necessary, right?

Comment: You either use the pip installed tensorflow and CUDA 11, or just install using conda and pick up the binary runtime it distributes. But don't do both. Right now you are probably running the pip tensorflow with the wrong runtime. If you set your environment correctly, you can use everything from conda. But you clearly aren't doing that. Choose one, it is up to you

Comment: You didn't follow exact official instructions, that's why you ended up with such an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of extensive research, it finally works on my computer: the latest versions of the components (i.e. `CUDA 11.2`, `cuDNN 8.1.0`) are not tested and not ensure a working result in TF 2.4.1. Therefore, this is my final configuration:

1. `nvidia-drivers-460.39` have `CUDA 11.2` drivers. However, you can still install `CUDA 11.0` *runtime* and get it from the [official NVIDIA archive for CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive). Following the installing instructions is still mandatory (i.e. adding the path variables and so on).
2. `cuDNN` library needs to be on the version 8.0.4. You can get it also from the [official NVIDIA archive for cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)

After installing both components on [these specific versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements), I successfully get:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

Num GPUs Available: 1
```

with a few debut messages indicating that the GPU libraries were correctly imported.

#### EDIT:

By the way! For the folks out there who use Pycharm, either you include the environment variables also in PyCharm, or make them system-wide. Otherwise you won't still get your TF to get the GPUs.